# Direct viewing to Print Preview Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, printing

Is there any way how to automatically view print preview when clicking a button in firefox browser?

> Currently when I clicks  html button this will appear

[image]

> It's hassle to click some buttons in firefox inorder to view print preview

[image]

> I want like this when I click the print button it should automatically appear this window.Is there any way how to do it?

[image]

> html

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" id="printTable">
<tbody><tr>
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>      
    <th>Points</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>      
    <td>50</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>        
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>        
    <td>80</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Johnson</td>        
    <td>67</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<br />
<br />
<button>Print me</button>
```

> javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function printData()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$('.printMe').click(function(){
     window.print();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="submit" class="printMe">
```

Comment: The result is the same [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGOG.png)

Comment: i think you are looking for this : https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Print-Preview-Popup-Plugin-jQuery/

Comment: thanks for your response , it's the same, all I want is  when I click the button this should appear [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11FeI.png) instead of this  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpGOG.png)

Comment: This plugin do it but it depend on your browser : http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/print/

Comment: thanks for your response, what browser did you use?